# Adding linker flags for CHECK_FUNCTION_EXIST

Tags: c, cmake, linker

I am working on a libwebsockets library, whose build script seems to be written in CMakeLists.txt, etc. I am new to cmake. The libwebsockets is a C library, I believe.

To make a long story short, I would like to add a -L option when CMake works on this line of the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites LWS_HAVE_SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites)
```

Or, just as an example:

```
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(foo)
```

I was able to notice that CMake has a .c file in /usr/share/cmake-/Modules. It has this line in the main function:

```
int main( /* some args */ ) {
 CHECK_FUNCTION_EXIST();
}
```

My understanding is that, in order for CMake to know whether the function is available or not, CMake compiles the .c file with -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXIST=foo, and conducts linking. When the linker (e.g. gcc, clang) does its job, CMake gives a bunch of linker options as configured -- e.g. -lssl, -lm, etc, in my case. If "foo" is not found, the linking fails with "undefined reference to foo." That makes CMake believes that the function is not available. If the linking succeeds, CMake seems to conclude that the function is available.

I'd like to add -L option to the linker options in that step. For example. clang or gcc must link against my local libssl rather than the system-widely installed one. For clarification, I do not need to build my libwebsockets itself through CMake. I just need the lws_config*.h file, which is some of the outputs of `cmake ..` command. In other words, I won't run `make -j 10` followed by `cmake ..`. I will have to run only `cmake ..`.

I have tried to set `CMAKE_{EXE,STATIC,SHARED}_LINKER_FLAGS`. While setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` did add -I options as wanted, those three LINKER options did not add -L option. What is the right way to achieve my goal?

My cmake version is 3.15.4.

Comment: So did you read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckFunctionExists.html  ? It's literally listed there which variables to use.

Comment: Thank you! I did try to search the documents with other keywords. But did not think of searching it with CheckFunctionExists.